# How can I loop a lottery number generator?

Tags: python, loops, generator

I have to generate random numbers for the Uk lottery.
I already have the code for that part but at the end, i have to ask the player if they would like to generate more and i dont know how to.
If it helps this is the last line of my code.

```
    if lines == 5:
print(a,b,c,d,e,f)
print(g,h,i,j,k,l)
print(m,o,p,q,r,s)
print(t,u,v,w,x,y)
print(z,aa,bb,cc,dd,ee)
```

I need help on both bits, don't judge the code as it works and we weren't told a specific way to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify---which part are you looking for help on: a) Asking the player, or b) creating more sets of numbers?

Comment: What are these values that you are printing in your code? Does the UK lottery have thirty numbers? Pardon my ignorance. (Perhaps some more descriptive variable names are in order :-) )

Comment: @user65439 obviously a console application or `print` wouldn't make much sense. @OP, what have you tried so far? Looking at a few examples of while loops should give you an idea how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import sample

numbers = range(1,50) # 1-49

def generate_draw(balls=6,population=numbers):
    return sorted(sample(population,k=balls))
```

Call `generate_draw()` as many times as you need. Though, you should probably check that you don't offer them the same draw twice.

```
>>> generate_draw()
[19, 31, 34, 39, 40, 44]
>>> generate_draw()
[4, 7, 18, 22, 25, 44]
```

If you want to a function to return multiple draws:

```
def multiple_draws(count=5):
    results = []
    for i in range(count):
        results.append(generate_draw())
    return results
```